# Get levelDB length/size through iterating the DB in synchronous way

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async.js, leveldb

I am trying a node.js app with levelDB.
suppose i have few entries in the DB, and need to query its size before i can do something.. ive implemented the getDBLength() func as :

```
function getDBLength() {
        let i = 0;
        console.log('aaaa');
        db.createReadStream().on('data', function(data) {
            console.log('bbbb');
            i++;
        }).on('error', function(err) {
            return console.log('Unable to read data stream!', err)
        }).on('close', function() {
            console.log('returning length as: ' + i);
            return i-1;
        });
    }
```

Output on calling this func from nodejs prompt:

```
console.log( 'Length: ' + getDBLength());

aaaa
Length: undefined
bbbb
returning length as: 1
```

the getDBLength() returns immediately as db.createReadStream() inside getDBLength is asynchronous operation.

Whats the correct way to know the length when i want?